# Show the differnce between versions with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to show the differences between versions? Like in SO once we creates a question after that if any modification will apply to that question it shows the changes. It shows whatever changes applied to that question when we clicks on link. Like new tags applied or question modification etc ..

Any gems or plugins?

Any Idea? Something like this ..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for versioning your model and tracking diffs, [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) is a very good option. It tracks model changes through diffs. And has a nice clean API, which will make traversing through diffs a walk in the park.

It is also incredible easy to write your own versioning system for ActiveRecord. I wrote one [here](https://github.com/swanandp/simple_versioning).

Answer (score 3):

I would use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

You can find a great screencast about this here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gem, it should also be compatible with Rails 3:

```
https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned
```

Comment: Can i achieve the same result as image in question with acts_as_versioned ?

Comment: you got multiple record, but you need to calculate the changes yourself.